# Is it possible to save Val?

Tags: revolution-60

The Walking Dead game also made claims about a game tailored by our choices, but ultimately just provided the ILLUSION of choice.  Is that the case here?  Is it possible for those missiles to hit their target at the end?  If I had chosen to kill Val, would Holiday have actually gone through with it?  Can Val actually survive the game, or will she always die somehow?

Answer (score 5):

this is Brianna Wu. I'm head of development at Giant Spacekat.

We had so many requests to let you save Val that we're going to spell out what happens to her in our next patch. It will be possible to save her on girlfriend mode. That may or may not end up being a good choice.

She will still be saved or not saved if you download the patch or not. You'll just see the outcome.